# issue in json response value not apperaring properly

Tags: json, laravel-5

```
$order_info = DB::table('order_assignments')
                                ->join('order', 'order_assignments.order_id', '=', 'order.id')
                                ->join('order_status', 'order.order_status_id', '=', 'order_status.order_status_id')
                                ->join('users', 'order.customer_id', '=', 'users.id')
                                ->join('address', 'order.address_id', '=', 'address.id')
                                ->where('delivery_boy_id', $delivery_boy_id)
                                ->where('is_accept', 1)
                                ->whereRaw('order_assignments.delivery_completed_at < order_assignments.time_of_assignment')
                                ->get();
                       //dd($order_info); 



                 if ($order_info) {
                    foreach ($order_info as $value1) {
                    $value = $value1;
                     $orderModel = new Order();
                     $order_info = $orderModel->getOrderDetailsForId($value->order_id);
                    $this->response['bill']= ['item' =>$order_info['orderDishes'],'service_charge' => $value->total_sercharge, 'total_amount' => $value->total_amount, 'comment' => 'completed on time', 'customer'=>['address' => $value->address, 'Name' => $value->name], 'distance_traveled' =>'7 k.m', 'picker' => 1, 'restaurant' =>['address' => 'c-3', 'lat' => '77.2222', 'long' => '77025698'], 'time_taken'=> '2hours', 'status' => 'completed', 'uid' => $value->order_id ];
                }
                    // $this->response['customer'] = ['address' => $value->address ];
                    return json_encode($this->response);  
                    } 

                 }
```

When i run this code its apperaring only last order id from databse in jason respose while there are two order id are in table. Please anyone help me to fix this problem

Comment: because you're overwriting your `$this->response['bill']`

Comment: how to fix it that i could get the both order id

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->response['bill'] = .... //
```

modify this line as below:

```
$this->response['bill'][]= ['item' =>$order_info['orderDishes'],'service_charge' => $value->total_sercharge, 'total_amount' => $value->total_amount, 'comment' => 'completed on time', 'customer'=>['address' => $value->address, 'Name' => $value->name], 'distance_traveled' =>'7 k.m', 'picker' => 1, 'restaurant' =>['address' => 'c-3', 'lat' => '77.2222', 'long' => '77025698'], 'time_taken'=> '2hours', 'status' => 'completed', 'uid' => $value->order_id ];
```

Comment: @princepriyadarshi welcome :) If you've any more query regarding this question let me know :) It would be very much appreciated if you can accept my answer which worked for you :)